# Deploying GitLab on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, minikube

I'm trying to deploy GitLab on Kubernetes using minikube through [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/kubernetes/gitlab_chart.html#deployment-of-gitlab-to-kubernetes) tutorial, but I don't know what values to put in the fields `global.hosts.domain`, `global.hosts.externalIP` and `certmanager-issuer.email`.

The tutorial is very poor in explanations. I'm stuck in this step. Can someone tell me what are this fields and what should I put on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to deploy GitLab on Kubernetes using minikube through this tutorial, but I don't know what values to put in the fields `global.hosts.domain`, `global.hosts.externalIP` and `certmanager-issuer.email`.

For the domain, you can likely use whatever you'd like, just be aware that when gitlab generates links that are designed to point to itself they won't resolve. You can work-around that with something like [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) or editing `/etc/hosts`, if it's important to you

For the externalIP, that will be what `minikube ip` emits, and is the IP through which you will communicate with gitlab (since you will not be able to use the Pod's IP addresses outside of minikube). If gitlab does not use a `Service` of type `NodePort`, you're in for some more hoop-jumping to expose those ports via minikube's IP

The `certmanager-issuer.email` you can just forget about, because it 100% will not issue you a Let's Encrypt cert running on minikube unless they have fixed cermanager to use the dns01 protocol. In order for Let's Encrypt to issue you a cert, they have to connect to the webserver for which they are issuing the cert, and (as you might guess) they will not be able to connect to your minikube IP. If you want to experience SSL on your gitlab instance, then issue the instance a self-signed cert and call it a draw.

> The tutorial is very poor in explanations.

That's because what you are trying to do is perilous; minikube is not designed to run an entire gitlab instance, for the above and tens of other reasons. Google Cloud Platform offers generous credits to kick the tires on kubernetes, and will almost certainly have all the things you would need to make that stuff work.

Comment: I purposefully omitted from my answer that I think minikube is a mind poison and should be drug out in the street and shot; it will **never** behave like a real cluster does, and thus what are you actually _testing_?!

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'm trying to solve a CI/CD challenge to get a job. I would be very grateful if you help me with this challenge. Unfortunately the description is in Brazilian Portuguese. https://gist.github.com/Pacheco95/37538c1863dfe5fcd2ec16cf6fdab430
Basically I need to deploy GitLab and Jenkins on top of Kubernetes, make them speak to each other and setup a CI/CD system that manage an hello world application.

Comment: The tutorials on the Internet has many commands  that does not work anymore. GitLab.com and Kubernetes tutorials does no help me to achieve my goal.
These are some of the tutorials I've tried:
https://dzone.com/articles/learn-how-to-setup-a-cicd-pipeline-from-scratch
https://medium.com/containerum/configuring-ci-cd-on-kubernetes-with-jenkins-89eab7234270
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin
https://itnext.io/deploy-jenkins-with-dynamic-slaves-in-minikube-8aef5404e9c1
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins

Comment: The problem in trying to set up a pipeline on your machine which has so many moving parts is not only due to the memory pressure, but also because CI/CD toys are generally pretty I/O intensive, too (especially with GL running its own postgres). If at all possible, I would recommend trying one of the low cost cloud providers, especially if it's to get a job -- you can think of any money as an investment rather than a cost. Then, ask more specific questions about specific errors you are encountering. Good luck!

Comment: I refer to https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab/blob/master/examples/values-minikube-minimum.yaml,  GitLab has been deployed in minikube, all pods status are `Running`,   but I don't know how to access GitLab, I change `global.hosts.domain` to `c.k8stest`, `global.hosts.externalIP` to `192.168.64.12` (which is my minikube ip), but https://gitlab.c.k8stest/ cannot open, What I need to do ? thanks

Comment: I fixed, I forget to enable ingress and kube-dns, thanks to https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/development/minikube/